# Does dotnet restore command restores all packages?

Tags: c#, api, docker, .net-core

I have a dotnet core 2.2 api application. There are 3 layers: API layer, Business Service and Data access layer. In Data Access Layer I have used *IHttpClientFactory*.

While running through docker I am getting below errors:

> warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Extensions.Http". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IHttpClientFactory' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/app/MyApp.Service/MyApp.DB.csproj]

Here is my docker file:

```docker
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build 

WORKDIR /app

COPY *.sln . 
COPY MyApp/. ./MyApp/ 
COPY MyApp.Application/. ./MyApp.Application/ 
COPY MyApp.DB/. ./MyApp.DB/
 
RUN dotnet restore
 
COPY MyApp/. ./MyApp/ 
WORKDIR /app/MyApp 
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS runtime 

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/MyApp/out ./ 

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```